# Can't send objects using Sockets

Tags: java, sockets, input, output

Hello Im writing an app in which client sends name of room to server, server creates it and then sends back whole list of rooms. I have problem with receiving this object from server also whats interesting when I close clients' app and open again I have list of rooms just like it should be. I refresh room list in client app but its always empty only reopening helps that's pretty weird and I don't know an issue of this.

On client side:

```
   getIs() method is returning is object
getOs() method returning os object

            this.os = new ObjectOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
            this.is = new ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());

        private void createRoom(ActionEvent event) {
        String roomName = "CreateRoom ";
        roomName += setRoomName();
        String response = null;
        try {
            client.getOs().writeObject(roomName);
            response = (String) client.getIs().readObject();
            System.out.println(response);


        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

    private void refreshRooms() {
        String response = null;
         try {
             client.getOs().writeObject("RefreshRooms");
             response = (String) client.getIs().readObject();
             System.out.println(response);
             rooms = (Rooms) client.getIs().readObject();
             System.out.println("Print in client: ");
             rooms.printAllRooms();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }




    }
```

Server:

```
this.os = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
    this.is = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());

public void run() {

String inputRequest = null;

        try {
            while((inputRequest = (String) ois.readObject()) != null) {
                System.out.println(inputRequest);
                handleRequest(inputRequest);
            }
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Client has disconnected.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

}

private void handleRequest(String request) {
    String response = null;
    String[] msg = request.split(" ");

    if(msg[0].equals("CreateRoom")) {
        try {
            oos.writeObject("You want create a room.");
            Room newRoom = new Room(msg[1]);
            rooms.addRoom(newRoom);
            System.out.println("Created room:  " + newRoom.getName());
            System.out.println("\n Print after creation: ");
            rooms.printAllRooms();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }else if (msg[0].equals("RefreshRooms")) {
        try {
            oos.writeObject("You want list of rooms.");
            System.out.println("Print before send.");
            rooms.printAllRooms();
            oos.writeObject(rooms);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

///EDIT:
So I removed PrintWriter and BufferedReader objects and now Im using only Object Streams. What doesn't work now is:

I create some rooms one after another and then refresh rooms list on clients app - in that case I get all rooms

But when I create one room refresh then create another and refresh I get only 1 room after 2nd refresh, so basically when I refresh server sends me always the same object from 1st send and I don't know how to change it.

Also Im printing these rooms on server side and always get all rooms so room creation is OK.

Comment: And your question is? NB You can't mix buffered streams on the same socket like this. Make up your mind. Either you're using  buffered readers and writers or object streams. You can't have both.

Comment: Does the server get the message?

Comment: Well I changed to object streams but I have the same problem.
Server get message but sends always the same object even If i modify it.

Comment: You need to investigate `ObjectOutputStream.reset()`. NB `readObject()` doesn't return null at end of stream, so looping on it is incorrect. It throws `EOFException`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to [flush](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedOutputStream.html#flush--) the buffered streams:

```
os.flush()
```

This will force the stream to actually send the bytes of the serialized object. Without that, the `BufferedOutputStream` might just wait around and buffer data, as the name says. This is done so that the size of the sent packets does not become too small, which would result in a lot of overhead if you want to send multiple objects.

If you are done, you should close the stream anyway.

Comment: I added os.flush() before sending this object but I didn't change anything.

Comment: How is flushing "before" supposed to help?

Comment: Sorry i meant after, it looks like:  oos.writeObject(rooms); oos.flush();

Comment: Class Rooms is an List of objects Room so I tried to send each element of this List in for loop and it works, isn't the best idea but I just can't send whole object of  Rooms.

Comment: If you've removed the `BufferedStream`s in the EDIT, then the answer is obsolete anyway. Consider cleaning your code up and closing all streams properly first. This here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html might be useful.